# How to get input from user with treeset in java?

Tags: java

I am using `Treeset` to sort edges, here's the code:

```
TreeSet<Edge> edges = new TreeSet<Edge>();

//Sample problem - replace these values with your problem set
edges.add(new Edge("0", "1", 2));
edges.add(new Edge("0", "3", 1));
edges.add(new Edge("1", "2", 3));
edges.add(new Edge("2", "3", 5));
edges.add(new Edge("2", "4", 7));
edges.add(new Edge("3", "4", 6));
edges.add(new Edge("4", "5", 4));

System.out.println("Graph");
KruskalEdges vv = new KruskalEdges();

for (Edge edge : edges) {
    System.out.println(edge);
    vv.insertEdge(edge);
}
```

I just want to take inputs from user instead of giving statically into `edges.add`

Comment: A sample for reading inputs from user's keyboard: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang/Systeminread.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I want to take it as graph with first two arguments would be graph co-ordinates and third would be weight, so that I can implement MST algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

If your `Edge` constructor takes two `String` arguments and one `int` argument then simply read two `String` and one `int` using [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), store them in variables and then pass them to the `Edge` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation of Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to figure out how to get inputs in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

You may use scanner to get inputs at runtime

```
//From command line
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

```
//From file
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("edges"));
while (sc.hasNextLong()) {...}
```

you'll then have to instantiate Edge objects with these values and use it in your TreeSet

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to prompt for 3 parameters of each `Edge` instance (You can do this via `Scanner` class.). Then process these parameters (I mean use `String` class functions, etc. ) to construct instances. Finally, add each instance to your edge set in the same loop. Sample code:

```
TreeSet<Edge> edges = new TreeSet<Edge>();

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int counter = 10;

while (counter > 0)
{
    System.out.println("Enter edge parameters:");
    String temp = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] params = temp.split("-");
    edges.add(new Edge(params[0], params[1], Integer.valueOf(params[2])));
    counter--;
}
```

**Note**: The loop above executes 10-times, it's just for demo, you can manipulate the loop yourself. It expects user to enter *dash(-)* as separator of the parameters. A valid user input could be like: *24-5-6* And also be careful about error handling, mismatching user inputs are not handled in this code.